# What is a best practice to receive JSON input in Django views?

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I am trying to receive JSON in Django's view as a REST service. I know there are pretty developed libraries for REST (such as [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)). But I need to use Python/Django's default libraries.

Comment: both of them, POST and GET

Answer (score 5):

`request.POST` is pre processed by django, so what you want is `request.body`. Use a JSON parser to parse it.

```
import json

def do_stuff(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    # do your thing
```

Comment: This leads to `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` in Python 3

Comment: @gtd thanks! You'll need to decode it first: `json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514077/get-request-body-as-string-in-django for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Send the response to browser using `HttpResponse` without page refreshing.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse,

import simplejson as json

def json_rest(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':True, 'error': 'You need to login First'}))
   else:
      return render(request,'index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
(r^'/','app.views.json_rest')
```

**client side:**

```
$.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url: "/",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
         console.log(result)    

       }
});
```

Comment: You are talking about a response. For response I have following mechanism:

 `@json
 def feed_one(request, id):
  sample = get_object_or_404(Sample, pk=id)
  return sample`

Comment: Where @json is decorator and looks something like:

`def json(fn):
 def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
  try:
   fn_result = fn(request, *args, **kwargs)
   json_result = {'is_successful': True, 'message': None, 'data': fn_result}
  except Exception as e:
   if DEBUG:
    raise e
   json_result = {'is_successful': False, 'message': e.message, 'data': None}
  return HttpResponse(to_json(json_result), mimetype='application/json')
 return wrapper`

Now I am writing response hadnling mechanism and need something like a code I shonw above.