# Get request body as string in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm sending a POST request with JSON body to a Django server (fairly standard). On the server I need to decode this using `json.loads()`.

The problem is how do I get the body of the request in a string format?

I have the following code currently:

```
body_data = {}
if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').lower() == 'application/json' and len(request.body) > 0:
    try:
        body_data = json.loads(request.body)
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps({'error': 'Invalid request: {0}'.format(str(e))}), content_type="application/json")
```

However, this gives an error `the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`.

How do I retrieve the body of the request as a string, with the correct encoding applied?

Comment: Does `request.read()` do the job?

Comment: @dhke, no, it gives the same, which surprised me actually. `request.body.decode('utf-8')` seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The request body, `request.body`, is a byte string. In Python 3.0 to 3.5.x, `json.loads()` will only accept a unicode string, so you must decode `request.body` before passing it to `json.loads()`.

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body_data = json.loads(body_unicode)
```

In Python 2, `json.loads` will accept a unicode string or a byte sting, so the decode step is not necessary.

When decoding the string, I think you're safe to assume 'utf-8' - I can't find a definitive source for this, but see the quote below from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

In Python 3.6, [`json.loads()` accepts bytes or bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). Therefore you shouldn't need to decode `request.body` (assuming it's encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: `utf-8` is also the default value of the first argument of the `decode()` method (check `help(bytes.decode)`)

Comment: In Python >= 3.6, `json.loads` can accept a `bytes` argument too, and it assumes it's encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 9: invalid start byte
python 3 7 7

Comment: @CoffeeinTime that error suggests that the request body isn't valid utf-8. Fix the client if you control it, or add suitable error handling if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the other end from where you receive this request does not convert the data to JSON before sending the request. Either you have to convert the data to JSON before you send, or just try accessing request.body in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's valid json though - if I use `request.body.decode('utf-8') ` then it works. Is there a reason not to do this would you say?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to end up with a dictionary of the data you have just sent to the server using JSON, save yourself the trouble of decoding the body yourself and use the  [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) dictionary-like object django already provides out-of-the-box.

So suppose you POST this to the server:

```
{ 'foo': 'bar' }
```

Then the following method

```
def my_handler(request):
    foo = request.POST['foo']
    print(foo)
```

Would print `bar` to the console

Comment: Well, I came across this question while I was reading about django, realised there is a much simpler solution, so I posted it. Is that a bad thing? Does it matter that it's an older question? Imho it's still relevant

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I needed! Better post than not post, never know who it will help.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `request.POST` only works if the request body is form encoded. It won’t work if the data is json encoded.