# Django DRF JWT authentication get token - JSON parse error - Expecting value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have simple Django DRF application setup which I have implemented JWT authentication.

I used the [Django REST framework JWT documentation](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

I am using curl to test the implementation.

I can successfully get a token using the following notation used in the documentation:

```
$ curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=password123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

The token is returned in following format:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNpdHJ1Y3AiLCJleHAiOjE1MTE2NTEyMTQsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiY3VydGlzLnBva3JhbnRAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.F1TSkxe5tQVpddetUdOJDdAPP1XB9Bimb5U3c75oWd0"}
```

However, when I try using this other variation, I get an error:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password123"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

The error I get is:

```
{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```

I also had the same error when trying to refresh or verify the token:

Refresh:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":"<EXISTING_TOKEN>"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-refresh/
```

Verify:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":"<EXISTING_TOKEN>"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-verify/
```

I was adding the token as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNpdHJ1Y3AiLCJleHAiOjE1MTE2NDg5MjIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiY3VydGlzLnBva3JhbnRAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.T5h_PSvzvKOZCPTS60x5IUm3DgAsRCRmbMJeGWZk3Tw"}' http://localhost:8800/api-token-refresh/
```

Am I perhaps adding the token incorrectly? Does it need some other formatting with quotes?

Comment: Have you overridden any views? How do your settings look like? We're actually using this in production and from what I'm seeing in the views and urls, we've added auth class to the login view and we've customized the urls and are calling the refresh_jwt_token directly.

Comment: One silly question, but have you escaped your data?

Comment: No just using the basic Class Based Views. Settings are pretty much straight from DRF tutorial implementation. Can you be more specific about escaping data?

Answer (score 1):

Those requests are sending data in two different ways. The first request sends it as form data (x-www-form-urlencoded) which is what your endpoint is expecting and the second request sends it as application/json.

I'm not sure that the library you're using will handle a json request out of the box so one option would be to create a custom endpoint and use something like the following:

```
import json

def ParseFormData(self, request):
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    // use django auth to authorize request and return token
```

You can read more about it in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514222/5443056

There's instructions for manually creating auth tokens in your library's documentation. Here's the code:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

Comment: He is using a library that does this for him, check the link he posted

Comment: Yea I saw that and just edited. I'm not sure he can achieve that functionality with that library unless he makes a custom endpoint to handle the request.

Comment: Yes the tokens are being created for me, and do work. Ok, perhaps DRF needs help parsing the JSON but the [Django REST framework JWT documentation](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage) does explicitly indicate that it expects DRF to be able to do so. It says in reference to the variation which is giving me the error:  _"Alternatively, you can use all the content types supported by the Django REST framework to obtain the auth token."_

Comment: Well I'm seeing a similar error on my end. I'm not a Python expert but it doesn't look like the library handles json requests judging from the code, but I could be wrong. It's not a big deal to build a custom route if needed.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest use json.dumps({*key:value*})