# How do I post to Django using Axios?

Tags: javascript, django, post, axios

I'm moving from Jquery AJAX to Axios since I'm using ReactJS so I think it's cleaner, I am having some troubles posting a simple request to the server, the post method goes through my view but whenever I `print(request.POST)`, I have an empty queryset (`<QueryDict: {}>`).

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: SITE_DOMAIN_NAME + '/my_url_name/',
  data: {
    'tes1':'test',
    'tes2':'test'
  },
  headers: {
    "X-CSRFToken": CSRF_TOKEN, 
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Django view is a simple ClassBasedView.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`request.POST` is only for form-encoded data. If you are posting JSON, then you should use `request.body` instead.

```
import json
json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

If you do this, you'll have to make changes to your class based view to use `request.body` instead.

If you want to get axios to send form encoded data instead, [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362) on GitHub might help.

Comment: Are there any risks using request.body?

Comment: No more than using `request.POST`. It's untrusted input so you should clean it (e.g. by using a form).

Comment: @Alasdair - should body always be decoded (`decode('utf-8')`)?

Comment: @Headmaster I *think* so. See [my similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514222/113962).