# Data from react axios post is not sending data to django

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send post data from react to django, however, the data is not attached to the post object. My react code looks something like this:

```
class Homepage extends React.Component {
createProject() {
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "localhost:8000/createProject/,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        data: { name: "projectname" },
    })
}
render() {
    return <div onClick={this.createProject}></div>
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path( "createProject/", views.createProject ),
]
```

views.py

```
def createProject( requests ):
    print( requests.POST )
    return JsonResponse({"this returns": "just fine"})
```

output from `print( requests.POST )` in views.py:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
```

If it matters, I'm using csrf_exempt on my django functions as there are no plans of deploying.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you define what method is in your client side? POST, GET, etc...?

Comment: I am defining the method in the config passed to axios. I forgot it in my question but it was defined in my code that gives an empty output. Question updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49430231/11360794
provided the appropriate solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print in the view

```
print(request.get.POST('data'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using django 2.2.  It throws an error: `File "/home/adam/dataview/backend/api/views.py", line 86, in createProject
    print( requests.get.POST("name" ))
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
`

Comment: Sorry, if I print `print( requests.POST.get( "name" )` it prints `none`

Comment: try print(request.get.POST('data'))