# JSON object sent from Javascript to Django Views is empty

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I'm trying to send some data from Javascript to Django through ajax.
Here is my JS code:

```
            var json_name = {'name': 123}
            $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'my url',
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
                },

            data: JSON.stringify(json_name),
            success: function (data) {
         //this gets called when server returns an OK response
            alert("it worked!");
            },
        error: function (data) {
             alert("it didnt work");
            }
        });
```

Here is my Views.py:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       request_data = request.body
       # data = json.loads(request.body)
       print(request_data)
       # print(data)
       return render(request, 'candidate/view.html')
    else:
       return render(request, 'candidate/view.html')
```

I get the output as `b''`

When I try to include these lines:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
print(data)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

I took some reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532573/ajax-post-not-sending-data-when-calling-request-post-in-django-view)

Can someone help me with this? If you need any additional information to solve this, I'll be happy to share.

Comment: and what does `json_name` contain in your JavaScript? Have you checked it's populated as you expect before sending the request?

Comment: Yes, I put console.log(json_name) before sending the request and it is outputted as: `{name: 123}`

Comment: How are you triggering that Ajax post? Is it on a button click? If so did you call `preventDefault()`? Show rest of the script and the html?

Comment: do you try
data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8')
print(data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get request body as string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514077/get-request-body-as-string-in-django)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying to post a request after an event is finished (file upload to AWS). No buttons or any other functions. I need that `json_name` to be transferred to my Django view after the event is finished. So I put this part of code after the completion of the event. So sorry, I can't really share the complete code here due to some reasons.

Comment: @Bast it is throwing me this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
`

Comment: I don't understand what the "event" is in this context. How is the file being uploaded to AWS? Is it being done in Javascript somehow? Please show the rest of that script.

Comment: @jacobian That link is pointing to what Bast suggested.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm recording a video, and when I click a button called `upload`, the video will start getting uploaded to AWS. When I get an alert message saying that the video is successfully uploaded to AWS, I need to send `json_name` to Django view so that I can do some processing on that. The piece of code I posted here has absolutely no connection with the rest of the code. I wish I could share the complete code, but it is something kind of confidential, I don't knw how to say...it has some information which I cannot publicly share. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After losing half the hair on my head, I solved it in the following way:

views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def myview(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('senddata')
        print(data)
    return render(request, 'candidate/view.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'candidate/view.html')
```

my JS code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my url',
            // contentType: "application/json",
            // headers: {
      //               'Content-Type':'application/json',
      //               'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
      //           },
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                senddata: JSON.stringify(json_name),
                },

            // data: json_name,

            success: function (data) {
         //this gets called when server returns an OK response
            alert("it worked!");
            },
        error: function (data) {
             alert("it didnt work");
            }
        });
```

When I run it, it shows `it didnt work` but I can see the output in my terminal i.e The data was passed.

I tried including the csrf token in the ajax request but it failed. Therefore I used csrf_exempt in my views.

This might be a dirty way of doing things, but it works for now. If anyone has a neat and better answer please post it here!!

Answer (score -1):

I've written a basic testcase on Django 1.11 with Python 3.6 and Python 2.7.

I have been using the following template file to test:

```
<button>Send data</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    var data = { name: 123 };
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function() {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error...');
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

And the following route, which delivers the template file and prints any AJAX data:

```
from django.http import response
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        request_body = request.body
        data = json.loads(request_body)
        print(data)
    return render(request, 'stackoverflowhelp/index.html')
```

I've not been able to reproduce the issue.

However, having done more research I found that the `json.loads` method in Python 3.6 supports `bytes` objects, while the [documentation for Python 2.7 `json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.loads) suggests it only supports string types. While the error you've posted reflects this, I've attempted to make this generate the same error as you're seeing but have had no success.

As you can see, I've not had to whitelist the method from CSRF protection. Based purely on the error you've provided, calling `decode` on `request.body` may work:

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        request_body = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        data = json.loads(request_body)
        print(data)
    return render(request, 'stackoverflowhelp/index.html')
```

Comment: `method: 'POST',
          url: 'my url',
          contentType: "application/json",
          headers: {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
                    },
                datatype: "json",
          processData: false,
          data: json_name,
`                                          Thanks for the information, it gave me some conceptual understanding. However, I still get the same output as `b' '`.

Comment: I can't see how this answer is at all relevant. OP is already converting the data to a JSON string. And `dataType` is for the datat that is *returned* by the server, not what is sent.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I've seen this kind of issue before and it's usually been because JQuery encodes the data as a query-string. I've since written a testcase and it appears to be sending the data correctly. I'm going to modify my answer with the solution.