# Get data non form data from post request in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, post

I try to submit data on change and change the response from the view based on the data from the POST request.

```
      $.ajax({
        url: $basicAnalysisChart.data("url"),
        type: "POST",
        headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:{
            selector1:$("#Select1").val(),
            selector2:$("#Select2").val()
        },
```

i tried getting to that data in my view with  `request.POST.get("Select1", "")` and  `request.POST.get("selector1", "")` but cant get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt format the json object right, so it couldnt work. Porblem solved

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: ...and it doesn't help future/other readers. Like, what was wrong with your original JSON object? And how did you format it right?

Answer (score 0):

As your data type is JSON, in django you should say

```
data = request.body
```

instead of:

```
request.POST.get("Select1", "")
```

From the documentation: "If you need to access raw or non-form data posted in the request, access this through the HttpRequest.body attribute instead."

here is the link to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: but if i do that i just get ``` b'[object Object]' ``` as data. and i cant find any info on how to procede from there

Comment: Alright, that is a different problem. Please search for handling of request.body in Django. Here is a question answered about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514077/get-request-body-as-string-in-django